# Kinetic.js: Click event for each rect

Tags: jquery, html, kineticjs

How do you create a click event for every Kinetic.Rect in a group?

Let's say i have this:

```
var bar1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
      x: 0,
      y: 100,
      width: 400,
      height: 10,
      fill: 'grey',
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 2
});

var bar2 = new Kinetic.Rect({
      x: 0,
      y: 100,
      width: 400,
      height: 10,
      fill: 'grey',
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 2
});
```

Is there a way to have the same click event for both bars?
Using jQuery possibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a `var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();` and add your bars to it then bind the layer with `.on`

```
layer.add(bar1);
layer.add(bar2);
//...
layer.on('click',function(e) {
          //...
          //bar1/bar2 is e.targetNode
```

see http://konvajs.github.io/docs/events/Multi_Event.html

otherwise

```
function handleClick(e) {
       //..
       //bar1/bar2 is e.target
         }

bar1.on("click",handleClick);
bar2.on("click",handleClick);
//...
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I do need to know which rect was clicked, I don't think that is possible this way.

Comment: e.target is a HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: figured it out, had to be e.targetNode. Thanks! Maybe you can edit your answer so i can accept the answer?

Comment: sorry, e.targetNode obviously if handler on the layer,  edited !